# Parsing iCalendar format

Tags: haskell

I need to parse iCalendar format, which is basically what is used by Google Calendar and almost all calendar apps.

I have found this package [iCalendar Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/iCalendar)
But I cannot figure out how to use the `parseICalendar` function in this package, if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong, it would be great.

Mainly I cannot figure out how to construct an argument for the Type `DecodingFunctions`

```
parseICalendar :: DecodingFunctions
               -> FilePath -- ^ Used in error messages.
               -> ByteString
               -> Either String ([VCalendar], [String])
```

My effort:

```
module CalendarReader 
( getCalendar
, getSummary
) where

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B      -- package "bytestring"
import qualified Text.ICalendar as ICal         -- package "iCalendar"
import qualified Data.Map as Map                -- package "containers"
import Network.HTTP.Simple                      -- package "http-conduit"


import qualified Time                           -- local module
import Constants

getCalendar :: IO B.ByteString
getCalendar = do
    request <- parseRequest $ "GET" ++ calendarURL
    response <- httpLBS request
    return $ getResponseBody response

getSummary :: B.ByteString -> Time.DateTime -> Int -> String
getSummary cal dateTime dayOffset = summary
  where
    summary = "Event Summary"
    ((ICal.VCalendar { ICal.vcEvents = vcEvents' }), _) = ICal.parseICalendar ?missingArgument? logFile cal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DecodingFunctions` is supposed to contains a function to convert your `ByteString` (binary array) to a `Text` (representing a string of unicode characters) and one to do the same to a case-insensitive representation (for comparison purpose I suppose). If your iCalendar is "normal" and is encoded in utf-8, you can simply use the [`Default`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-0.5.3/docs/Data-Default.html#t:Default) instance of `DecodingFunctions` :

```
parseICalendar def logFile cal
```

(don't forget to import def from somewhere)

If your iCalendar is not in Utf-8, you'll have to use a `decode...` function from [Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.1/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Encoding.html) and `mk` from [Data.CaseInsensitive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/case-insensitive-1.2.0.4/docs/Data-CaseInsensitive.html#t:CI). For Utf16 you would have :

```
decodings = DecodingFunctions decodeUtf16LE (mk . decodeUtf16LE)
```

with the right imports.

Comment: Yeah, this works. What took me extra time though was figuring out that I need to import Data.default for def